# Templating a View with "multiple fields"

Tags: 7, views, theming, media

I'm templating (modifying the `.tpl.php` files) of a View which has a field with multiple outcomes. This can be controlled using the "Multiple field settings" options. (see screenshot)

How I can achieve more freedom in templating it's look and feel? I know I can edit `views-view-field.tpl.php` file but that doesn't help much because that file has only a single line of code!

```
<?php print $output; ?>
```

Any idea how I can edit/modify individual fields of a multiple-field?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Multiple Field in a View]

Comment: the $output should be an array. Do a dpm($output) to see its contents. Then just look over the array and print the fields to your liking